# Volume of a solid of revolution with change of variable

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, volume, solid-of-revolution

I want to calculate the volume of the solid of revolution around the x-axis of this figure

$x = (1-t^2)/(t^4+4)$

$y = (t+1)*(1-t^2)/(t^4+1)$

for t between -1 and 1. In the figure below the plot is shown

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yUHj.png)

In my opinion to do this I have to calculate the integral of

$\int_{0}^{0.25}\pi * (y_{upper}^2 – y_{lower}^2) dx$.

The solution in my book is

$\int_{-1}^{1}\pi * y(t)^2 * (dx/dt)  \text{dt}  $

I do not understand why after changing the variable of integration to $t$ the upper and lower part of the curve or not subtracted anymore.

Comment: What do you mean by upper and lower? If $y$ is a function of $x$ on the given interval, then the integral is just $\int πy^2 \, dx$ over that interval.

Comment: Please have a look to the link to the plot I posted (I don't have enough reputation to include the picture). It is not a function.

Comment: OK, seen. A moment, please.

Comment: I think you are right. This might have been an answer oversight on the part of the authors. I think what happened is that they thought the curve defines a function over that interval of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide the integral into two parts, one from $0$ to $1$ and one from $-1$ to $0$. In fact you should plot $(x(t),y(t))$ separately for those two intervals. You will notice that these two intervals form the upper and lower branches of your curve. Moreover, when you vary $t$ from $-1$ you go on the lower curve from $(0,0)$ and return on the upper branch. But that means that you increase $x$ then you decrease it. You can therefore write $$\int_0^{0.25}(y_{upper}^2-y_{lower}^2)dx=\int_0^{0.25}y_{upper}^2dx-\int_0^{0.25}y_{lower}^2dx=\int_0^{0.25}y_{upper}^2dx+\int_{0.25}^0y_{lower}^2dx$$

Comment: Do you mean that the solution from the book is correct?

Comment: I did not follow it to the end, but I think it is